# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de una barra específica, en un gráfico de Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Estoy construyendo unos gráficos con *Highcharts*, pero tengo problemas para cambiar los colores de las barras de dicho gráfico, colocando `colorByPoint` en **true** las barras obtienen un color difrente automaticamente sin posibilidad de escoger cuál color se quiere en cada barra, y colocando `colorByPoint` en **falso** se puede elegir el color que uno prefiera utilizando `color`: **'#colordesupreferencia'**, pero al usar el color de esta manera, todas las barras de la serie toman ese único color. Aquí dejo el código que tengo para que entiendan a qué me refiero

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic']
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                colorByPoint: true
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [26, 41.5, 100.5, 11.2, 210.0, 216.0, 137.0, 48.5, 21.4, 194.7, 99.6,156.3]
        }, {
            colorByPoint: false,
            data: [26, 41.5, 100.5, 11.2, 210.0, 216.0, 137.0, 48.5, 21.4, 194.7, 99.6,156.3],
            color: '#F75E25'
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Necesito cambiar únicamente el color del mes de marzo (ejemplo) en la serie 2, donde todas las barras tienen un único color, ya que no se me ocurre algo más para poder cambiar el color de ese mes en específico.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Necesitas alterar las opciones de Highcharts con `setOptions` asi:

```js
$(function () {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        colors: ['#058DC7', '#50B432', '#9D561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#9F9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4']
    });
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic']
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                colorByPoint: true
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [26, 41.5, 100.5, 11.2, 210.0, 216.0, 137.0, 48.5, 21.4, 194.7, 99.6]
        }, {
            colorByPoint: false,
            data: [26, 41.5, 100.5, 11.2, 210.0, 216.0, 137.0, 48.5, 21.4, 194.7, 99.6],
            color: '#F75E25'
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: Perfecto, con esto me funciona, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

La documentación de Highchart dice que la [estructura de la data tiene para asignar el valor, los títulos, el color y varias opciones más](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.data)

```
data: [{
    y: 1,
    name: "Point2",
    color: "#00FF00"
}, {
    y: 1,
    name: "Point1",
    color: "#FF00FF"
}]
```

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        }
        ,plotOptions: {
            series: {
                colorByPoint: true
            }
        }
        ,series: [{
            data: [
             { y: 2, name: "Ene", color: "blue" }
            ,{ y: 26, name: "Feb", color: "#FF00FF" }
            ,{ y: 41.5, name: "Mar", color: "#00FF00" }
            ,{ y: 100.5, name: "Abr", color: "#FF00FF" }
            
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: Interesante, este método también es útil, gracias!